querySelector return null even though DOM is loaded
This is my first time trying to make a Chrome extension. I want to track changes to an element on a page using MutationObserver, but I get null when trying to find the element I need. I checked for DOM loading - it didn't help. Such an element definitely exists, I tried to run the code in the browser console - everything works.
I have this error
TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Helper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "helper.html",
    "default_icon": "helper_icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.site.ru/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "./content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["injected.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }]
}

content.js
console.log('content script start');

function run() {
    console.log('The DOM is loaded');
    let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
        console.log(mutationRecords);
    });
  
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('.items_9ujCP'), {
        childList: true, 
        subtree: true,
        characterDataOldValue: true
    });
    console.log(document.querySelector('.items_9ujCP')); // return null
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", run);

I also tried to change "run_at" to "document_end" in manifest. But then the message "The DOM is loaded" is not even displayed in console.
I've read similar questions, and it seems like everyone has a similar code working. I'd be glad if someone could help or explain what's wrong.

perhaps the element with that class is loaded dynamically

@JaromandaX I think so, then how do I get it

a mutation observer on the body to detect when it is added?

@JaromandaX I executed code from function in content script in browser console, when page is loaded. And mutation observer is working.

.items_9ujCP looks like a dynamically-generated CSS class-name in React - or similar - if that's the case then it's no surprise your querySelector fails because the element's class="" attribute will be different every time you reload the page.

@Dai no, class name is always the same

Set a debugger breakpoint on the first statement in function run (or use the debugger keyword) and use the step-through debugger to single-step through until the first document.querySelector('.items_9ujCP') call - then copy-and-paste the that expression to the console and run it there and show us what you get.

@Dai at this breakpoint querySelector return null, but the content on the page has not yet been displayed (the site itself is showing a loading animation)

That's not how MutationObserver is used. Observe document or document.body and check for the element's existence inside the callback. Example: link.

I used SetTimeout earlier and it helped. But I thought it was a workaround.
Thank everyone for help
